# Java Generics Difference between List of Wildcard and List of Box of Wildcard?

Tags: java, generics

Why is

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

while at the same time

```
List<Box<?>> boxList = new ArrayList<Box<Object>>();
```

is not allowed

Also what does `List<? extends Box<?>>` mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a classic generic puzzle. Often our brain is smart enough to infer new rules from known ones, but that's not the case with generics. Your question illustrates two common problems with wildcards:

- You cannot assign a `List<Box<Object>>` to a `List<Box<?>>`
- You can actually call `add()`on a `List<Box<?>>` while you can't on a `List<?>`

The solution to the first problem is that generics are invariant: there's no subtype relation, no matter what types are given to the type variables, unless there are wildcards involved. Even if `Box<Object>` is a subtype of `Box<?>` the subtype relation does not hold for the enclosing lists.

The rule for problem #2 is that wildcard are not *captured* recursively. In fact `new ArrayList<Box<?>>()` is a valid expression, while `new ArrayList<?>()` is not. Also, as I said previously, you can add elements to a `List<Box<?>>` because the instatiation of the generic type `List<E>` yields:

```
// This actually doesn't compile, it's just an explanation of the
// instantiation process
public interface List<Box<?>> {
  void add(Box<?> box);
}
```

Comment: Hi Raffaele, I understand the 1st point which you made regarding the non covariancy in generics. So this means List<?> is an exception and can be compared to Object[] thus allowing to instantiate with anything. However can you help in explaining the second point you made.

Comment: Raffaele : "Also, as I said previously, you can add elements to a List<Box<?>> because the instatiation of the generic type List<E> yields". I could not understand this line.

Comment: @confusedmind If you have a reference to a `List<?>`, can you call `myList.add(something)`?

Comment: Thanks for the response .No referencing using List<?> l, does not allow us to add anything since it could be possible to add apples to oranges. However List<Box<?>> allows to add Box<Apple> as well as Box<Orange> due to which I am getting confused?

Comment: @confusedmind well it's a really good starting point :) I explained the last bits it in the second section of my answer. The *capturing* of wildcards stops at the first level: think of `List<E>` as a text file written in a special language that allows you not to manually define a `ListOfIntegers`, `ListOfStrings` with the appropriate signatures (and field types), etc. First-level wildcards are then `ListOfCapture1`, `ListOfCapture2`, etc., while second levels are left as they are: `ListOfBox<?>`

Comment: @ Raffaele : So this means that First-Level wildcards stops at ListOfBox  while the second level is ? which is not taken into consideration. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Yes. `List<Box<?>>` is translated to the interface at the bottom of the answer, so the method `add(Box<?>)` can be applied with any subtype of `Box<?>` (`Box<Integer>`, `Box<String>`, `Box<? super Class<?>>`)

Comment: Itratin u desc abv                                               
List<?> l = new ArrayList<Object>(); (cn be seen as) ===> List<? extends Object> l  = new ArrayList<Object>();
due to which above is allowed and not alowd to ad nythg due to PECS Prdcer extends Cnsumr Super

and List<Box<?>> l1 =  new ArrayList<Box<String>>(); //Nt alowd since Gnerics is no-covariant bt
List<Box<?>> listOfBoxesNew = new ArrayList<Box<?>>(); // This is allowed and
listOfBoxesNew.add(new Box<String>());
listOfBoxesNew.add(new Box<Integer>());// both allowed since Box<?> is suprType of Box<String> and Box<Integer>

Answer (score 2):

Because a `List<Box<?>>` accepts boxes containing anything. The following is thus valid:

```
List<Box<?>> boxes = new ArrayList<>();
boxes.add(new Box<Integer>());
boxes.add(new Box<String>());
```

Whereas a `List<Box<Object>>` only accepts instances of `Box<Object>`. The following is thus invalid, since a `Box<Integer>` and a `Box<String>` are not `Box<Object>`.

```
List<Box<Object>> boxes = new ArrayList<>();
boxes.add(new Box<Integer>());
boxes.add(new Box<String>());
```

Now if your question is "why is `Box<String>` not a `Box<Object>`" the answer is that if it were, you could do the following, which would ruin the type-safety of generic types:

```
Box<Integer> boxOfIntegers = new Box<>();
Box<Object> box = boxOfIntegers; // this is actually invalid
box.add("I'm a string in a box of integers. Ouch!");
```

Comment: Hi JB, Thanks for the response                                      if                                                            List<Box<?>> boxes = new ArrayList<>();
boxes.add(new Box<Integer>()); // This is allowed while             at the same time in case                                           if                                                               List<?> boxes1 = new ArrayList<Object>();                          boxes1.add() // this is not allowed

Comment: Because a List<?> is a list of some type, but you don't know the type. So you can't add anything to it, because you can't know that what you're adding has the right type. Whereas a List<Box<?>> is a list of boxes, and the compiler thus knows that it contains boxes, and you can thus add boxes to it.

Answer (score 0):

`List<A>` is a subtype of `List<?>`, where `A` is a type (that satisfies the bounds of the wildcard, if any).

However, `List<A>` is not a subtype of `List<B>`, if `A` and `B` are types that are different (regardless of any sub typing relationship between `A` and `B`).

You have probably seen the case where `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`, even though `String` is a subtype of `Object`. (I will not go into the reasons here.)

The same thing is happening where `List<Box<String>>` is not a subtype of `List<Box<?>>`, even though `Box<String>` is a subtype of `Box<?>`. Note that even though there is a `?` in there somewhere, it is deep inside as part of the type `Box<?>`. The `?` does not act at the level of the parameter of `List`, so it does not allow you to take different types of lists.

If you want a type that can accept `List<Box<String>>` and `List<Box<Integer>>`, etc., you may want to use `List<? extends Box<?>>`. Note that here there is a `?` at the top level. This allows the type argument of `List` to be any subtype of `Box<?>`, which includes `Box<String>`, `Box<Integer>`.